# IMAP array values changing spontaneously - PHP

Tags: gmail, imap

My company uses script-generated emails to correspond with clients. Until now, we've had to manually sort through these emails, look up client info, print and file them. I'm writing a script that does this automatically and it was working fine until 10 minutes ago when Google stopped sending the subject with `imap_fetch_overview()`.

Here's how I'm doing it:

```
$msgov=imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$uid,FT_UID);
$msgsub= $msgov[0]->subject;
$msgfr= $msgov[0]->from;
$msgid= $msgov[0]->uid;
$message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$uid,1,FT_UID);
//echo message info, then message
echo "...";
```

And that worked fine until about 10 minutes ago when I started getting this error: `Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$subject in C:\wamp\www\gmil\index.php on line 113`

So I proceed to `echo var_dump($msgov);` and suddenly it's not showing the subject anymore.. According to [The Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetch-overview.php) it should be giving me the subject. Am I doing something wrong or am I just unlucky enough to be doing this at the exact time Google decided to stop sending it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm dumb.
After one message not didn't contain a subject, it stopped checking for that value in all subsequent loops. I solved it like this:

`if(isset($overview[0]->subject)){$sub=$overview[0]->subject;}else{$sub="No Subject";}`

and then called `$sub` instead of `$overview[0]->subject`.